# Installing Lubuntu on to Android tablet and switching os in between

Tags: lubuntu, android, ubuntu-for-android

I would like to install Lubuntu onto my tablet, as it seems more lightweight than ubuntu. However, it seems there are only images for Windows/ Mac? For Android devices, what image shall I download?

I've also found an [article](http://androlinux.com/android-ubuntu-development/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-android/) about installing Ubuntu on Android phone. And by installing VNC, it seems that one could "switch" from OS to OS on the phone, i.e. I could be viewing the Ubuntu OS on the phone via a VNC viewer, and closing the viewer gives me back the Android OS.

My questions are:

1) What ubuntu/lubuntu image (windows?mac?) shall I download in order to get this done?

2) My ultimate goal is to run some windows programs on a Android tablet. I am planning install a lubuntu os and then wine... what will be the minimum hardware requirement in order to do this?

Thank you very much!